# Putting Faker Gem Values to a Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, cucumber, capybara, faker

I'm writing automated tests using Cucumber, Capybara, WebDriver, SitePrism, and Faker. I am new to this and need some help.

I have the following steps..

```
Given (/^I have created a new active product$/) do
@page = AdminProductCreationPage.new
@page.should be_displayed
@page.producttitle.set Faker::Name.title
@page.product_sku.set Faker::Number.number(8)
click @page.product_save
@page.should have_growl text: 'Save Successful.'
end

When (/^I navigate to that product detail page) do
 pending
end

Then (/^All the data should match that which was initially entered$/) do
 pending
end
```

In config/env_config.rb I have set up an empty hash...

```
Before do
# Empty container for easily sharing data between step definitions

@verify = {}
end
```

Now I want to hash the value generated by Faker in the `Given` step so I can validate it saved properly in the `When` step. I also want to enter the value generated by faker in the script below into a search field.

```
@page.producttitle.set Faker::Name.title
```

1. How do I push the values generated by faker to the @verify has?
2. How do I pull that value and insert it into a text field?
3. How do I pull that value to verify the save value equals the value generated by faker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How do I push the values generated by faker to the @verify has?**

A [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html) is simply a dictionary of key-value pairs, which you can set with `hash[key] = value`.

The key can be a string  `@verify['new_product_name'] = Faker::Name.title`

The key can also be a symbol `@verify[:new_product_name] = Faker::Name.title`

Since the value you generate may be used multiple times within the step definition (once for storing it in the @verify hash, and once for setting the field value) I personally prefer to first store it in a local variable, and reference that where needed.

```
new_product_title = Faker::Name.title
@verify[:new_product_title] = new_product_title
```

**2. How do I pull that value and insert it into a text field?**

You can reference values by their key. So after you have stored the value in the hash, you could do this 
`@page.producttitle.set @verify[:new_product_name]`

Or if you stored it in a local variable as suggested above, you would just do this

`@page.producttitle.set new_product_name`

**3. How do I pull that value to verify the save value equals the value generated by faker?**

Similarly, you can assert that a field value equals what you've stored in the hash. An example would be `@page.producttitle.value.should == @verify[:new_product_name]`

Putting this all together:

```
Given (/^I have created a new active product$/) do
  @page = AdminProductCreationPage.new
  @page.should be_displayed

  # Create a new title
  new_product_title = Faker::Name.title

  # Store the title in the hash for verification
  @verify[:new_product_title] = new_product_title

  # Set the input value to our new title
  @page.producttitle.set new_product_title

  @page.product_sku.set Faker::Number.number(8)
  click @page.product_save
  @page.should have_growl text: 'Save Successful.'
end

When (/^I navigate to that product detail page) do
   pending
end

Then (/^All the data should match that which was initially entered$/) do
  @page.producttitle.value.should == @verify[:new_product_title]
end
```